# Is there an any advantage to using Laplace transforms over Fourier transforms in Statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, laplace-distribution

Do you know the advantage of the Laplace transform over the Fourier transform in statistics? I say, it's more restrictive and I couldn't find any advantage

I asked this because the professor used Laplace's in a hydrodynamics model, I was wondering what the advantage of that would be.

Comment: Fourier transform is a special case of the Laplace transform. Sometimes different transformations of an expression are valuable in proving results or deriving desired expressions.

Comment: @Galen In Fourier's statistics, it is more comprehensive

Comment: Is there a difference between Fourier's statistics and [Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis)? If not, there is certainly a lot more to say about empirical spectra and their properties. Otherwise, some definition of "Fourier's statistics" might help me understand what you're describing.

Comment: @Galen Laplace's is only defined for positive variables

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.

Comment: It probably doesn't answer your question in particular, but since you mention hydrodynamics in particular: ["*The transform has many applications in science and engineering because it is a tool for solving differential equations. In particular, it transforms linear differential equations into algebraic equations and convolution into multiplication.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Comment: The particular model in your professor's case might have been more conveniently transformed by the Laplace transform. Is that plausible?

Comment: ["*Unlike the Fourier transform, the Laplace transform of a distribution is generally a well-behaved function.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Fourier_transform) I am not sure exactly what they mean by that, but that might hint that there is an advantage.

Comment: @Galen I do not think so. Its useful properties are essentially the same as Fourier's. That is, where $L(X)$ is the Laplace transform of the distribution of the random variable $X$, given independent $X,Y, L(X+Y)=L(X)L(Y)$ and weak convergence equals weak convergence of the transforms

Comment: Okay, so if there is an advantage to Laplace transforms, it does not come from turning convolutions into products.

Comment: Perhaps there are specific families of functions that are nicer under Laplace transform, but offhand I do not know what those would be.

Comment: @Galen The Laplace transform is a special case of the Fourier transform.  When probability distributions are transformed, the Laplace transform (aka moment generating function) does not necessarily exist, but the Fourier transform (aka characteristic function) *always* exists.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the clarification. What about the claim that the Laplace transform is define for a non-negative parameter while the Fourier transform is definitely over all real numbers?

Comment: @Galen I don't understand that claim because it's unclear what you mean by "parameter."  Are you perhaps observing that the Laplace transform is useless for analyzing most probability densities, because it doesn't even consider their values on negative numbers?

Comment: @whuber I suspect it comes from how it is written on wikipedia: $$\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st}dt$$ The integration here is for non-negative time.

Comment: In contrast, the Fourier transform may be given by:

$$\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{- 2 \pi i t \xi} dt$$

The integration here is for all time.